# sending high quality audio over the in the internet to a single point

Tags: audio, internet

I am trying to find out software to connect point to point but the audio quality has to be real good. Mumble seems to be for voice so it does not meet my demands. The problem is further aggravated by the fact that I have to install the software only on my computer. The receiving end will use VLC or Windows Media Player. Thus the stream from my computer to the receiving end has to be mp3 or similar. Is it possible? This problem has come up because of social distancing of COVID-19 and hopefully it is temporary. Can anybody help please? Right now I am using a stream through Shoutcast but there are problems of latency etc. Please help!!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! So what OS is your computer using? And are paid options acceptable? Further, what will be the audio source to stream (e.g. line-in/mike of your computer, sound files (which formats), etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLC as the source (creator) of the stream as well as the receiver. A helpful google search would be "stream privately over the internet with vlc" but basically on the source end you open VLC, hit ctrl-s for streaming options, pick the media file to stream, add a destination with  a protocol (note that a destination here would be better off called a "server" - you're configuring the local machine to stream the file - you aren't choosing anything about the receiver for the stream) hit go..

.. and then on the remote place that will receive your stream they choose to stream and enter your ip address and port (whatever you chose when setting up the "destination") and your VLC will send them the data (unaltered if you untick active transcoding)

Remember that you might have to configure port forwarding on your router so they can connect to your machine

For steps and pictures:

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-privately-stream-video-with-vlc-for-windows/

Or

https://forums.tomsguide.com/faq/how-to-stream-videos-over-the-internet-with-vlc.23235/

---

Alternatively take a look at Open Broadcast Studio - it can stream audio from your PC to various places like YouTube or Vimeo, and your consumer can watch it there in a browser. Because sites like YouTube operate content delivery networks you should find that streaming is more reliable. It's possible to restrict the access of a YouTube video so that it's not listed for public view or needs a Password to view it - which might meet your appetite for having the stream be private

Answer (score 0):

As a complete alternative (hence the new answer) you could consider creating a VPN server so that the remote person can dial into your home network and then they can just choose which file to stream (play in their VLC) after mapping a network drive to some share on your computer. OpenVPN is a free software that will let you create a VPN that the built in Windows VPN client can connect to